# How do I delete multiple document in firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection 'Cart' in firebase cloud fire store, in that collection I have 10 documents.

{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} these are the documents name or id.

I have a list view where I am getting the ids of the document and from that list I am selecting and trying to delete those.

I am trying to delete multiple documents from that collection.

I am trying to delete documents(6,2,7,4,5).

in firebase docs there is only how to delete single and multiple documents from fire store

so how can to implement this in flutter??

please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175235/how-to-delete-multiple-documents-from-cloud-firestore#:~:text=To%20delete%20multiple%20documents%2C%20you,()%20method%20for%20this%20purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously Firebase Firestore has no way to delete multiple documents, you can use `for loop` to achieve that.
You can make a list of the ids which you want to delete in Firestore
lets say

```
List _deletedIds = [6,2,7,4,5];
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= _deletedIds.length - 1 ; i++){
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Cart').doc(_deletedIds[i]).delete();
    }
```