# How to delete multiple fields from multiple documents in firestore through the REST API?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore

So far I have been deleting fields of documents through the REST API with the appropriate `PATCH` method. The API request as constructed in Postman is as follows:

url: `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project name}/databases/(default)/documents/{collection name}/{document name}/?updateMask.fieldPaths={name of field for deletion}`

body of request:

```
{
    "fields": {}
}
```

with the approriate authorization headers.
However this method can delete a single field from a single document.

How can I construct the request so that I can delete multiple fields from multiple documents on one go?

Comment: Have you tried [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)? Here is similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48175690/18265570) which might help you. and have a look at this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/batchWrite) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to delete fields from multiple documents. A batched write is a set of write operations on one or more documents.
You can use `delete()` class of batched writes to delete fields from multiple documents.

For more information you can refer this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48175690/18265570) and this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/batchWrite)

### **Update:**

Currently the [v1 API & v1beta1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch#http-request) only allows deleting multiple fields in a single document. So, I’m afraid that you may have to call API multiple times. And I don’t think there any other [API methods](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest) that will help to delete multiple documents. I believe batched writes [REST resources](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/batchWrite) would be the good workaround for this.

If you think that, it is a valid feature request you can raise request [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features)

Comment: Thanks again, however I am looking for a REST API solution, and the `delete` class I believe is part of the js client library implementation. The solution I am looking for contains the structure of the API call (url, body). Also the API methods linked to are for deleting documents and not fields of documents (one uses the `DELETE` api method, while the other, the `PATCH` method.)

Comment: @Mario I updated my answer. Can you have a look at my answer?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this matter, it seems the workaround with REST resources is the only option currently.